# Apps disappeared when Moto E booted

Tags: motorola-moto-e

My wife turned on her Moto E 2nd Gen yesterday morning, and according to her it redownloaded everything from the Play Store. After this, hardly any application would work.

On getting home from work I investigated and found:

- Webview was missing
- the Gallery App was corrupt
- a few other applications wouldn't start

Installing Webview fixed most problems, and Gallery App needed reinstalling too. The few other applications are third-party ones, and I will reinstall those as we find they don't work.

Why did this happen? Is it a known bug in Android, or something more serious like a hardware problem?

(The phone has an SD card slot, but we don't use it)